# How do i handle a boolean with a option tag

Tags: php, html

here is my html

```
<select name="optional_system_type" class="option_system_type">
   <option selected="selected" value="0">Select the System type</option>
      <option value="0">Single</option>
      <option value="1">Multiple</option>
</select>
```

The field that i am trying to use the data for is a boolean and it checks to see if this is a single or multiple system...if the system is single i want to use the value 0 and 1 for multiple. The problem i see is how do i handle the "Select the System type" and is there a better way to handle this all together. It seems that i would need to change the value from 0 on the "Select the System type" option for it not to have conflicts

any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checkbox. checkbox and radio box are not for true/false.

Comment: No way. Where did you get that idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly assign it as bool. Leave the first value as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Options are many. Here's one. Try replacing `0` with `single` and `1` with `multiple`. After all, those are the real options, not `0` and `1`.

If you really want to represent a Boolean then you should use a check box, not a select, nor radio boxes.